# Get a copy of iphone lock screen

Tags: iphone

I no longer have the photo I used for my iPhone lock screen, and I would like to retrieve a copy of it, or a full screen shot of the lock screen without the slider bar and time/date display.  Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to keep a background from an older version of iOS that was no longer available.  I did the following.

1. Take a screenshot of your lock screen by pressing the **Lock** and **Home** buttons simultaneously.
2. Get the screenshot onto a computer by email or syncing.
3. Go to [Google Image Search](http://images.google.com/), press the camera icon, and upload the screenshot.
4. Find a suitable copy to download.

Unfortunately, if it's a photo you took, this won't show any results unless you've also uploaded the photo to the internet at some point.